# Swipe ViewPager with animation on RecyclerView horizontal scroll- Android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager, android-animation

I am developing an Android app in which I have one `ViewPager` on top and one horizontal `RecyclerView` below the `ViewPager`.

When I scroll the `RecyclerView`, I am updating the `ViewPager` item with `viewPager.setCurrentItem(position)`. So that the `ViewPager` will swipe to that position.

It is working fine. But the `ViewPager` does not swipe with animation. It only moves to the current position.

I want apply some animation while swiping the `ViewPager` on `RecyclerView` scroll. How can I implement that animated behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

Try with

`viewPager.setCurrentItem(position, true)`

As per the [documentation of the ViewPager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager#setcurrentitem_5), it allows moving to that position smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use fade In effect for animation.
you should import this class in your file...

```
public class FadePageTransformer implements ViewPager.PageTransformer {
    @Override
    public void transformPage(@NonNull View page, float position) {
        page.setTranslationX(page.getWidth() * -position);
        if (position <= -1.0F || position >= 1.0F) {
            page.setAlpha(0.0F);
        } else if (position == 0.0F) {
            page.setAlpha(1.0F);
        } else {
            // position is between -1.0F & 0.0F OR 0.0F & 1.0F
            page.setAlpha(1.0F - Math.abs(position));
        }
    }
}
```

And after include that class you need to set your view pager like this...

viewPager.setPageTransformer(false,new FadePageTransformer());

it Will help you to implement animation effect in view pager